# Drag / Drop ListView prevent editing TextViews in list

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a List View which each row can be dragged using the Drag/Drop framework in Android. The strange thing is that in one list view I can drag/drop onto another row's textView and it inserts the underlying data element.

So if I have a Name displayed w/ the data element of a phone number, and I drag & drop 
John Smith    Dragged onto   Johnny Football  becomes
John321-231-5232ny Football

The phone number is automatically dropped where my finger was on the text view.. I don't want this, and wracking my head on what may cause it..

I thought that I could enable my fragment to (including my listView) to implement the OnDragListener, and just return true..  But that did not help..

Maybe I am missing some xml property?

I have another list view which does NOT do this, and I can't figure out what is different..

Comment: I was able to bypass the issue, I happened to be using my own TextView implementation and was able to just set the onDrag listener on an implementation there, and pretty much ignore it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like my issue is that to enable faded edge on my textViews I had to enable inputType="text"

This looks like it implements the drop target automatically.

I just had to add my own onDrag listener, and ignore.